# UITextView content size calculation after setting text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I've added a `UITextView` with Autolayout constraints in Storyboard. I am filling it up with text coming via API response. I want to use a custom vertical progress bar as user scrolls through `UITextView`. For this I need to know the current position and total height of content in `UITextView`. When I write this code in

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   NSLog(@"Hello : %f %f",_readerTextView.contentSize.height, _readerTextView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

I get the current position but I don't get the total content height during initial stages of scrolling. I only get the total content height as I reach bottom of `UITextView`. How do I get the total content height as and when I set the text in my `UITextView`?